# i want to get specific value in list using python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, split

```
import netifaces as ni
temp=ni.interfaces()
print ni.ifaddresses(temp[0])
for a in ni.ifaddresses(temp[0]).iteritems():
    print a
```

this is show me below:

```
{-1000: [{'addr': '24:f5:aa:30:ff:ff'}], 2: [{'broadcast': '11.4.9.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '11.4.9.22'}], 23: [{'addr': 'fe80::34cc:afcf:c9d6:e25c%11'}]}
(-1000, [{'addr': '24:f5:aa:30:ff:ff'}])
(2, [{'broadcast': '11.4.9.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '11.4.9.22'}])
(23, [{'addr': 'fe80::34cc:afcf:c9d6:e25c%11'}])
```

but i want to get only addr value like 24:f5:aa:30:ff:ff

how to get specific value in list using python?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use indexing to get the related values to `addr` in your dict:

```
for a in ni.ifaddresses(temp[0]).iteritems():
    print a[1][0]['addr']
```

Comment: Given that the first item is a dictionary that doesn't contain a key of `1`, won't this immediately fail?

Comment: `1` is second item that is a list in your case! then you can access to its first element that is a dictionary.

Comment: In this case, the first `a` is a dictionary, with each key being a number and each value being a `list` that holds a single dictionary. At no point in the entire given data structure is there any `list` with a valid index of `1`. Try creating an iterable out of the output given in the question, then iterate over that with your loop body and tell me it doesn't give you an error.

Comment: Isn't the first `a` a dictionary `{-1000: [{'addr': '24:f5:aa:30:ff:ff'}], 2: [{'broadcast': '11.4.9.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '11.4.9.22'}], 23: [{'addr': 'fe80::34cc:afcf:c9d6:e25c%11'}]}`?

Comment: Can you add an MCVE so that I can see what data structure you're using where `print a[1][0]['addr']` actually works?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 based on  the result of `print a`  that are your items for example in item `(23, [{'addr': 'fe80::34cc:afcf:c9d6:e25c%11'}])` the second elements (`a[1]`) is ` [{'addr': 'fe80::34cc:afcf:c9d6:e25c%11'}]` in this element the first and unique item is `{'addr': 'fe80::34cc:afcf:c9d6:e25c%11'}` so till now we have `a[1][0]` after this you can get the desire value with `a[1][0]['addr']`

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do.

```
aux=[{-1000: [{'addr': '24:f5:aa:30:ff:ff'}], 2: [{'broadcast': '11.4.9.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '11.4.9.22'}], 23: [{'addr':'fe80::34cc:afcf:c9d6:e25c%11'}]},
(-1000, [{'addr': '24:f5:aa:30:ff:ff'}]),
(2, [{'broadcast': '11.4.9.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '11.4.9.22'}]),
(23, [{'addr': 'fe80::34cc:afcf:c9d6:e25c%11'}])]

import collections

def my_func(the_val):
        if not isinstance(the_val, collections.Iterable) or isinstance(the_val, str):
                return
        if isinstance(the_val, dict) and the_val.has_key('addr'):
                print "------------------->", the_val['addr']
        for e in the_val:
                if isinstance(the_val, dict):
                        my_func(the_val[e])
                        continue
                my_func(e)

my_func(aux)
```